# Wicket form missing data on submit

Tags: wicket

I have a ModalWindow which has a form, which has a TabbedPanel, which has two AbstractTabs which, on which there is a DataTable on each of them, with input elements.

So: ModalWindow > Form > TabbedPanel --> Tab1 (Panel) > DataTable (there are two tabs)

Within the ModalWindow, I added to the form 3 buttons, like the following:

```
    // save button
    final GbAjaxButton save = new GbAjaxButton("save") {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        @Override
        public void onSubmit(final AjaxRequestTarget target, final Form<?> form) {
            System.out.println("Saving something...  ");
        }
    };
```

I can see the data being sent via POST to the backend, but I can't seem to be able to access any of the fields in the DataTables.

Some parts for the code are:

```
tabA = new AbstractTab("Tab Name") {
    public Panel getPanel() {
        return new SomeNewPanel(panelId,<somedata>); // <-- this has the DataTable with inputs
    }
}
Form form = new Form("formNameInHtml");
form.add(new TabbedPanel("htmlName", tabs);
```

I would really appreciate some insight on this problem.

Thanks.

Comment: @martin-g I will stop using Stack Overflow due to unconstructive and useless observations like yours. I am tired of all the people who think they know stuff and criticize legitimate questions. Get busy.

Comment: `I can see the data being sent via POST to the backend, but I can't seem to be able to access any of the fields in the DataTables.` - this is non-sense to me. It needs clarification. You neither tell us the types of the form components' models, nor the way you try to read the POST data in onSubmit().

Answer (score 2):

From [ModalWindow javadoc](https://ci.apache.org/projects/wicket/apidocs/6.x/org/apache/wicket/extensions/ajax/markup/html/modal/ModalWindow.html), "If you want to use form in modal window component make sure that you put the modal window itself in another form (nesting forms is legal in Wicket) and that the form on modal window is submitted before the window get closed."

Wicket automatically adds a form outside the modal window, so if you want to use a second form inside you should override `org.apache.wicket.markup.html.form.Form#isRootForm()` and have it return true.

Comment: Hello @atha , thanks but the markup was indeed embedded in a sub form. The problem ended up being the id of the markup itself. Wicket' front end Ajax was submitting the wrong inputs. Really rare.